# How to patch configuration for Sitecore deployed in Azure App service

Tags: azure, paas, patch-configuration

I need to patch a configuration for my Sitecore deployed on Azure App service. Should I go to `App service -> Advanced Tools` use Kudu to upload configuration patch files to `App_Config\Include` or is there another way of doing it in PaaS model Sitecore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use Kudu Console to upload configuration patch files.
   see the blog post: [Copying and unzipping files using Kudu on Azure App Service](http://blogs.recneps.net/post/Copying-and-unzipping-files-using-Kudu-on-Azure-App-Service)
2. From your FTP client example [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/index.php).
   In the Web App, go to FTPS Credentials in the Deployment Center.
   You can get the hostname, username, and password from the created App Service. See the blog post (Step 3): https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configuring-ftp-server-for-azure-app-service/
3. The ideal solution is a patch your config file in your project solution and deploy it by CI/CD pipeline.

**Note:** Solutions 1 and 2 will restart your App Pool and recycle. Your application will go down after implementation.